# Como ver os valores das variáveis em tempo de execução?

Tags: visual-studio, debug

Como posso fazer para saber os valores das variáveis de uma aplicação em tempo de execução?

Quero saber qual o valor de algumas variáveis pra saber se o programa está agindo da forma correta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O normal é aparecer isso quando está *debugando*, se não está aparecendo no seu Visual Studio pode usar <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> e depois <kbd>A</kbd> (apenas as variáveis que estão sendo manipuladas neste momento) ou <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> e depois <kbd>L</kbd> (mostra todas variáveis em escopo), conforme a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Só funciona quando estiver em execução do *debug*.

Você poderá navegar pelas variáveis, abrir seu conteúdo nos casos de não escalares, como mostra esta imagem:

[image: Local variables debug]

Dá para ir acompanhando as mudanças de valores (fica vermelho) em cada passo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Lembrando que para conseguir acompanhar as mudanças são necessários pontos de interrupção para parar o programa e olhar as condições naquele momento que esbarrou no ponto. Se esbarrar no mesmo novamente, interrompe novamente. Não usei muito, mas se não me engano é isso.